# Is it possible to connect to TCP port 0?

Tags: networking, tcp

Listening to TCP port 0 allocates a free port number on the system for me.

But what happens when I try to *connect* to TCP port 0? The obvious answer is: "It doesn't work":

```
$ nc localhost 0                 
nc: port number too small: 0
```

Where in the system is this handled? In the TCP stack of the OS kernel? Are there Unixes where connecting to TCP port 0 would work?

Comment: In theory you could build a custom TCP stack in which listening on or connecting from port 0 works, which means that two such implementations could talk to each other on port 0.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Just to make sure we're on the same page (your question is ambiguous this way), asking to bind TCP on port 0 indicates a request to dynamically generate an unused port number.  In other words, the port number you're actually listening on after that request is not zero.  There's a comment about this in `[linux kernel source]/net/ipv4/inet_connection_sock.c` on `inet_csk_get_port()`:

```
/* Obtain a reference to a local port for the given sock,
 * if snum is zero it means select any available local port.
 */
```

Which is a standard Unix convention.  There could be systems that will actually allow the use of port 0, but that would be considered a bad practice.  This behaviour is not officially specified by POSIX, IANA, or the TCP protocol, however.<sup>1</sup>  You may find [this interesting](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2014/10/25/pretending-port-zero-is-a-normal-one/).

That's why you cannot sensibly make a TCP connection to port zero. Presumably `nc` is aware of this and informs you you're making a nonsensical request.  If you try this in native code:

```c
int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
struct sockaddr_in addr;
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = 0;
inet_aton("127.0.0.1", &addr.sin_addr);
if (connect(fd, (const struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr,"%s", strerror(errno));
}
```

You get the same error you would trying to connect to any other unavailable port: `ECONNREFUSED`, "Connection refused".  So in reply to:

> Where in the system is this handled? In the TCP stack of the OS kernel?

Probably not; it doesn't require special handling.  I.e., if you can find a system that allows binding and listening on port 0, you could presumably connect to it.

---

<sup>1. But IANA *does* refer to port 0 as "Reserved" ([see here](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml)).  Meaning, this port *should not* be used online.  That makes it okay with regard to the dynamic assignment convention (since it won't actually be used).  Stipulating that specifically as a purpose would probably be beyond the scope of IANA; in essence, operating systems are free to do what they want with it, including nothing.</sup>

Comment: It looks like the same idea as address 0.0.0.0 in ipv4. A reserved value, and used by the OS and programs for a special purpose. As an analogy, in radio there are reserved frequencies that no one uses for transmissions, but are used internally in equipment.

Comment: @richard no, 0.0.0.0 has a different meaning ;) it is used to designate an invalid, unknown or non applicable target or as "broadcast"

Comment: @AndreaCi wasn't broadcast 255.255.255.255?

Comment: @ratchetfreak 255.255.255.255 is broadcast. 0.0.0.0 has two meanings depending on context.  In programming it's synonymous w/ `INADDR_ANY`, which is what richard is referring to (the system will replace it with a default).  But actually using the address on a network seems to have the implications Andrea mentions (except not so clear that it counts as "broadcast"): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0

Comment: +1 @ratchetfreak for using the word “Wasn't” to refer to an ipv4 address. Long live ipv6.

Comment: Is it possible to get the randomly assigned port number somehow? I can image a scenario when the server can listen on a random port and report that port to a central server etc.

Comment: @yegle http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046616/sockets-how-to-find-out-what-port-and-address-im-assigned

Answer (score 6):

Asking for port 0 triggers the operating system to search for and allocate the next available port. This avoids you having to hard-code a specific port or having to search for an available port. My Linux Mint system returns

```
nc: port range not valid
```

to

```
nc localhost 0
```

Answer (score 2):

`nc -l 0` will ask the OS to listen on port 0. But as has been remarked above, most operating systems will see the 0 and invoke their particular customs for choosing a positive-numbered port for your application, so `nc` winds up listening on some port like 56514.

Comment: most operating systems will, ok, which don't?