# What am I doing wrong trying to write a bash script that returns the number of the next available port?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, networking, grep

I'm trying to write a script that takes a port number as an argument. It returns the next port that is not assigned to anything, and checks it by using the file `/etc/services`. If the port is taken (i.e. listed in the document), it adds one and then tries again.  I can't seem to get this script to return anything for "found" - it always equals 0 so I never enter the while loop.  What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

port=$1
found=$(cat /etc/services | grep -o '[[:space:]]$port/' | wc -l)

while [ $found -ge 1 ]; do
    $port=$($port+1)
#done

echo "found: $found"
echo "port: $port"
```

(ignore the comment in front of `done`, that's not the problem)

Comment: You're not reinitializing found inside the loop, and you can't assign $found; you want found= ...

Comment: Plug for shellcheck.net for the syntactic error checking

Comment: I have transcribed your image to text.  For a bit of rationale behind this, see [this Meta post](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086)

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180492/is-it-possible-to-connect-to-tcp-port-0/180500#180500

Comment: I wonder if you meant for the `grep` check to be done within the loop, now you'd just return the next number even if that was reserved too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Overview

There are just a few minor errors with this script, and a few stylistic things I would change.  Let's go through the original line-by-line:

```
#!/bin/bash

port=$1
```

A typical `#!` line and a simple assignment, we're off to a good start.

```
found=$(cat /etc/services | grep -o '[[:space:]]$port/' | wc -l)
```

This line has a small issue that one may not notice at first glance.  Since `$port` is in *strong quotes*, `'…$port'`, it won't expand to its value.  You'll want to use *weak quotes* instead, `"…$port"`.  Also, you don't really need `cat` here.  `grep` takes a filename as an argument, but if it didn't you could always use *redirection* (`grep 'pattern' < /etc/services`).  Further, `grep -c` writes a count of matching lines, so `wc -l` is redundant here as well.

```
while [ $found -ge 1 ]; do
    $port=$($port+1)
done
```

The loop seems *almost* fine.  You'll want to quote the entities in the test in case `$found` could possibly be empty.  Also, you assign with `port=`, not `$port=` (but you've used the correct form above, so I assume this was just a typo).  Finally `$($port+1)` means (if `port` is `22`, for example) "The output of the command `22+1`".  Clearly you want "The result of the arithmetic expression `22+1`", which is the very similar `$(($port+1))`.

```
echo "found: $found"
echo "port: $port"
```

These lines are alright as is.

## Considering the logic

Now, if you make all of the above changes so that the program is *syntactically* correct, it still will not do what you want.  You don't list a "correct" output, so I'm assuming you want:

```
found: <the number of occurrences of $1 in /etc/services>
port: <the next free port>
```

If these assumptions are incorrect, let me know in the comments and I will edit accordingly.

The script as is will never return if the given port *does* appear in `/etc/services` because you never update `found`.  So you may think it would be wise to copy the `found=…` line into the loop, but that is not so!  If you did that, then the script would always return `found: 0`.  I think the best thing to do here is to create a *function*:

```
found () {
    grep -co "[[:space:]]$1/" /etc/services
}
```

but now the exit value of this function can directly work as a condition. You'll want to quiet the output so it doesn't appear along with yours, and then you'll no longer need the `-co` flags, but you will want `-q`:

```
while found "$port"; do
```

Then, to return the number of occurrences of the input port, it would be

```
echo "found: $(found "$1")"
```

or you could use `printf`.

## Putting it all together

I think this is the script you were trying to write:

```
#!/bin/sh

found () {
    grep -q "[[:space:]]$1/" /etc/services
}

port=$1

while found "$port"; do
    port=$(($port+1))
done

printf 'found: %d\nport %d\n' "$(found "$1")" "$port"
```

## Bonus

As I was writing this, my initial reaction was that counting lines matching a given pattern could be done in `awk` as well as `grep`.  It then occurred to me that the entire program could be written in `awk`.  As a bonus, here is one implementation of that (though here I assume that `/etc/services` is sorted by port number):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS = "[ \t/][ \t/]*"
    ARGC = 2
    PORT = ARGV[1]
    OPORT = PORT
    ARGV[1] = "/etc/services"
}
($2 == OPORT) {
    FOUND = FOUND + 1
}
(NEXT == 0 && NR > 1 && $2 > PORT) {
    NEXT = ($2 > PORT + 1) ? PORT + 1 : NEXT
    PORT = $2
}
END {
    printf "found: %d\nport: %d\n", FOUND, (FOUND == 0) ? OPORT : NEXT
}
```

Comment: I got that much.  On my system, if you run this with a port number of 22, it will say `found: 3, port: 24`, as in "There were 3 entries for port 22 in /etc/services, and the next available port is 24".  Are you looking for something different?

Comment: @Kay I originally posted an incorrect `awk` version.  Then I removed it, but decided to fix it and put it back in.  You might try both the `bash` and `awk` versions.  You'll find that the `awk` version is noticeably faster, because it does not need to search through the entire file for each increment of `PORT`

Comment: I have to object to `'[[:space:]]'"$1"'/'` on aesthetic grounds. The `[]/` aren't special in double quotes, so you could just do `"[[:space:]]$1/"` and avoid the multi-quote dance...

Comment: @ilkkachu After thinking for a while, I agree with you.  Edited to universal weak quotes.  I was already in violation of my own preference for strong quotes whenever possible with `"1"`

Comment: This would beea lot more idiomatic if the function's exit code was 0 for found, non-zero otherwise. Capturing the output number and comparing it lexically to another is clumsy, inelegant, and error-prone, and a common antipattern.

Answer (score -1):

Minus the math part, here's a quick and dirty POC to accomplish what you're going for, but using an "if" statement in lieu of "while" loop conditions for your logic.

```
#!/bin/bash

port=$1
echo $port | while read a; do
found=$(cat /etc/services | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,5}/' | sed 's/^/ /' | grep ' '$a'/')
if [[ $found ]];
then echo port $a is being used
else echo port $a is not being used
fi
done
```

Edit: The issue was stemming from the $found variable.  the single quotes in the grep make $port get interpreted literally, so its grepping for the string 
' $port/' instead of ' 80/' for example.
fix: just change the single quotes to double quotes.

found=$(cat /etc/services | grep -o "[[:space:]]$port/" | wc -l)

Comment: I haven't read this thoroughly, but "grepping for a space in front of the port numbers" is not what `[[:space:]]` means.  That is a POSIX character class that matches _any_ whitespace character, including tab, formfeed, or U2008 (thin space)

Comment: @Fox you are right about the [[:space:]],  I did not know that. 
In that case all you need to do is change your single quotes to double quotes to allow string interpolation.  
The single quotes interpret '$port' as a literal instead of substituting the value, which should be a number in this case.
    `found=$(cat /etc/services | grep -o "[[:space:]]$port/" | wc -l)`